# Unable to convert ejbRef for ejb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

**QuestionCommonBusiness**

```
public interface QuestionCommonBusiness {

    void create(Question question);
    void update (Question question);
    void delete(Question question);
    Question read(Integer id);

    List<Question> all();
}
```

**QuestionLocalBusiness**

```
public interface QuestionLocalBusiness extends QuestionCommonBusiness {

}
```

**QuestionManagerEJB**

```
@Stateless
@Local(QuestionLocalBusiness.class)
public class QuestionManagerEJB implements QuestionLocalBusiness {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void create(Question question) {
        entityManager.persist(question);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Question question) {
        entityManager.merge(question);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Question question) {
        entityManager.remove(question);
    }

    @Override
    public Question read(Integer id) {
        return entityManager.find(Question.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Question> all() {

        TypedQuery<Question> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(
                "allQuestions", Question.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**QuestionController (JSF bean)...I don't know if I use this correctly**

```
 @Named
    @RequestScoped
    public class QuestionController {

    @Inject
    private QuestionLocalBusiness questionManager;

    private List<Question> questions;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        questions = questionManager.all();
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

}
```

**Error**

> ```
> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public
> ```
>
> com.myapp.interfaces.QuestionController.initialize() on
>   com.myapp.interfaces.QuestionController@29421836
>
> ```
> root cause
>
> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public
> ```
>
> com.myapp.interfaces.QuestionController.initialize() on
>   com.myapp.interfaces.QuestionController@29421836
>
> ```
> root cause
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to convert ejbRef for ejb QuestionManagerEJB to a business object of type interface
> ```
>
> com.myapp.application.QuestionCommonBusiness
>
> ```
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
> ```

Comment: Does it work if you use `@EJB` instead of `@Inject`? And what if you put `@Local` on the interface instead of the concrete implementation?

Comment: It works when I change (@)Inject to (@)EJB in the JSF bean. And I am having the beans.xml in the WEB-INF folder and in the META-INF for the rest of the projects (EJB Project, JPA project... made with Eclipse wizard)

Comment: Well, that'll be another Weld bug. In your case the wrong interface is been picked for `@Local`. Look like to be related to this: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16186

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to [Glassfish Weld issue 16186](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16186). The wrong interface is been picked for `@Local`, namely the supermost interface.

You've 2 options:

1. Just use `@EJB` instead.
2. Get rid of the `QuestionCommonBusiness` superinterface.

Needless to say that option 1 is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Or you may include QuestionCommonBusiness.class in your @Local annotation:

```
   @Stateless
   @Local({QuestionLocalBusiness.class, QuestionCommonBusiness.class)
   public class QuestionManagerEJB implements QuestionLocalBusiness {
      ...
```